# Value from UItextfield to double value and save to core data

Tags: ios, uilabel

I am trying to display a value which is a  double in my table view controller. I get the value from a user through a text field.one input is string and another is a double.I store it in the core data. I used the NSfetchRequest to display it to the table view. The table view cell has 2 labels into which the string and double go. When I run only the string values are seen in the table view not the double. How do I fix this

```
> Blockquote
      override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let Cell : TableViewCellFixed = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! TableViewCellFixed

        let data : NSManagedObject = List[indexPath.row] as! NSManagedObject
         //cellName and cellPrice are UILabels

        Cell.cellName.text = data.valueForKey("name") as? String

        Cell.cellPrice.text = data.valueForKey("price") as? String



        return Cell
    }
```

p.s :I tried Cell.cellPrice.text =  data.valueforkey("price") as Double and it gives an error : Cannot assign double to String

> Blockquote
>   // add  to core data

```
@IBAction func AddSave(sender: UIButton) {
    let appDel :AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let theContext : NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
    let theEnt = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Entity", inManagedObjectContext: theContext)

    let newItem = Model(entity : theEnt!,insertIntoManagedObjectContext: theContext)

    newItem.name = addName.text!
    let num :Double = (addPrice.text! as NSString).doubleValue
    newItem.price = num  
    do
    {
       try theContext.save()
    }
    catch {

    }

    print("name \(newItem.name)")
    print ("price \(newItem.price)")
    print ("double \(num)")


    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

in the console the output is 
name Grammy
price 6.9466761353417e-310
double 600.0

Comment: if you want to do some math you can set a double variable for that .. if you want to show the double value you have to cast as string . label.text only accpet string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like this

To Store double in `coredata`

```
let num :Double = (addPrice.text! as NSString).doubleValue
let price = NSNumber(double: num)
ewItem.price = price
```

Retrieve double value from `coredata`

```
 if let price = (data.valueForKey("price"))?.doubleValue {
     cell.cellPrice.text = "\(price)"
}
else {
     cell.cellPrice.text = 0
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes it did Thank you so much . Though it shows nil instead of the value the use enterd . I get the vlaue from the user through a textfield. In order to save it to the core data attribute which was of type double I had to cast it to a double . I did it like this  newItem.price = (addPrice.text! as NSString).doubleValue
 Why is it becoming nil? Is it because of the casting? Thanks for answering

Comment: It says error : missing locale . I added locale before data.valueforkey like this  Cell.cellPrice.text =  NSString(format: "%f",locale :data.valueForKey("price") as! String  and still showed an error saying cannot covert anyObeject to NS locale type

Comment: Still getting that missing locale error. I noticed that the value is getting converted to double correctly but when I print the value that is stored in the core data that value is nil. So any thoughts regarding that ?Thank you

Comment: Have you try to print that value before converting it to string. Also add the code that you have written to store value in `coredata` in your question.

Comment: I updated the code in the question . Kindly check it . Thank you

Comment: I printed the value before conversion . If i give in 500 it prints 500 correctly. So there's an issue in save only

Comment: Try to use `NSNumber.numberWithDouble` while storing doble in your coredata. So that it will store proper double value.

Comment: Can you give me the exact Syntax please. I really need to get past this little error. I'll be very grateful. Thanks

Comment: It worked :) But its storing the value as optional 500.0. How do I change that ?

Comment: print the value before assigning to label and  check that.

Comment: before it just prints 500 but in the table view and in the print statement for newItem.price its showing optional 500.0 in the console

Comment: There is no issue with that `optional` it is displaying because you have `optional wrapped` the object. What is value displaying in label.

Comment: Now its printing 500 in console but in table view alone its showing optional

Comment: in the label its showing optionAL(500.0) when I printed to the console . I printed cell.cellPrice.text

Comment: Error: Cannot convert value of anyObject to expected argument

Comment: I resolved it . I did it like this if let price = (data.keyforvalue("price") as NSString))?.doubleValue { cell.cellPrice.text = "\(price)"} else { cell.cellPrice.text = 0 }

Comment: Because that is what I modified to get the output. Your answer helped me save in core data .  I modified his answer to store it in label . Thank you very much . you really helped.

Answer (score 0):

Cell.cellPrice.text = "\(date.valueForKey("price"))"

Comment: It resolved the error but on display it shows ("%ld",nil) in my table view. Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 > Blockquote
          override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let Cell : TableViewCellFixed = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! TableViewCellFixed

        let data : NSManagedObject = List[indexPath.row] as! NSManagedObject
         //cellName and cellPrice are UILabels

        Cell.cellName.text = data.valueForKey("name") as? String
        let price = data.valueForKey("price")
        Cell.cellPrice.text = "\(price)" 



        return Cell
    }
```

Comment: Nope . Still getting a blank display .  Thank you for answering

Comment: Its displaying nil .

Comment: I get the value for price from the user using a textfiled and save it to the core data . my attribute price for the entity is a double. so when I get the value from a textfield I have to cast it to a double . I do it like this                  newItem.price =(addPrice.text! as NSString).doubleValue . Is it possible that this is storing the nil in my price and thats whyI'm getting this nil in my display? And if so how do I correct it?

Comment: Just print the value before saving it to Core Data. also if the value is nil try inserting 0 instead of nil.

Comment: I did print the values. The conversion has some error.t  The name value is storing properly but for the price on the console the value is printing 6.93815075733012e-310 . I gave the value as 10000 in the textfield

Comment: Some issue with retrieving price value from textfield try something likes this let myPrice = addPrice.text
        let val: Double = Double(myPrice)!

Comment: On execution it termintes .  I did it like let myPrice = addPrice.text let newItem.price = Double(myPrice! )! I tried if let myPrice = addPrice.text! {newitem.price = ( myprice as NSString).doubleValue but this gives nil

Comment: Can you paste complete code as How you are doing it?

Comment: @IBAction func AddSave(sender: UIButton) {
        let appDel :AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let theContext : NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
        let theEnt = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Entity", inManagedObjectContext: theContext)

        let newItem = Model(entity : theEnt!,insertIntoManagedObjectContext: theContext)
        
              newItem.name = addName.text!
        
        if let num = addPrice.text{
            newItem.price = (num as NSString).doubleValue
        }

Comment: @IBAction func AddSave(sender: UIButton)
    {
        let appDel :AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let theContext : NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
        let theEnt = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Entity", inManagedObjectContext: theContext)
        let newItem = Model(entity : theEnt!,insertIntoManagedObjectContext: theContext)
        newItem.name = addName.text!
        
        
        let mystring = addPrice.text
        let val: Double = Double(mystring)!
        newItem.price = val
    }

Comment: It crashes when I use let mystring = addPrice.text let val: Double = Double(mystring)! newItem.price = val

Comment: Bad execution at thread. I can run it on simulator but when I input the value and save it crashes

Comment: Set a Breakpoint on Exception and check... you will see the Exception... there should be something..

Comment: I cant figure it out. I've been stuck on this for a while. Thank you for your help

Comment: if you can figure out on which line you are getting exception, that can help, App Crashing will not help... anyways let me know if y9u find anything on your own.. All the best!!

Comment: The conversion doesnt have an error . I used var num : Double = (addPrice.text! as NSString).doubleValue and assigned newItem.price = num. Using print I printed the value of num and price. price prints as some weird value I showed before. Num prints correctly as 300.0 . So the error is in the save. Any thoughts about that? Thanks

Comment: can you just paste the Entity Model, also you should get the stack trace for save error...